# How to add controls to buttons at runtime when button count is unknown? (C#)

Tags: c#, button, count, runtime, browser

I have a Web Browser that I'm working on, and I'm currently adding bookmarks. The user will be able to add and delete as many bookmarks as (s)he likes. The program will detect the amount of bookmarks at runtime and make as many buttons as needed. Here's my code:

```
bookmark_url = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\IAmAPerson_Web_Explorer\bookmarks\bookmarks.txt");
bookmark_names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\IAmAPerson_Web_Explorer\bookmarks\bookmark_names.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < bookmark_url.Length; i++)
{
     Button button = new Button();
     button.Left = i * 75 + 9;
     button.Top = 50;
     button.Text = bookmark_names[i];
     this.Controls.Add(button);
     button.Click += (sender, e) =>
     {
         webBrowser1.Navigate(bookmark_url[i]);
     };
     Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Everything works fine exept the response of the button clicking. The code throws an out-of-range exception when I click on any of the buttons. The exception occurs on the line with this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(bookmark_url[i]);
```

Can anyone help with my problem? Like I said, the rest of the code works perfectly until I click on the buttons.

Also, I tried putting the defective line of code inside a try...catch statement, but then it doesn't do anything (probably because it keeps throwing exceptions). The code for that looks like this:

```
try
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(bookmark_url[i]);
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Also, to keep this from being marked as a duplicate, I looked, and I DID find other questions like this, but all of those questions knew how many buttons they were going to have. This code doesn't know until it reads the files.

EDIT: The following information might help - I'm using Windows Forms in VS Express 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of a modified closure. The final value of the variable `i` is `bookmark_url.Length` when the `for` loop is done running. Because of an [issue with "for" loops](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx), the final value of `i` is being stored in all of your `Click` events. Then when you click any button, it's trying to get a line out of your text file that doesn't exist.

Store `i` in a temp variable inside the loop, and then assign the temporary variable in the `Click` event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookmark_url.Length; i++)
{
    var iTmp = i;
    ...
    button.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(bookmark_url[iTmp]);
    };
    ...
}
```